# How to implement multiprocessing with multiple geoprocesses?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, raster, geo, arcpy

I am relatively new to Python and thought I would give a stab at multiprocessing.  I have a script that runs well in IDLE or as an ArcMap toolbox script.  After perusing these forums and docs.python, I made an attempt at incorporating my working script into a multiprocessing one.  However similar working examples on this forum are, none address data processing as I would like to.  I hope it is feasible.

Basically, the script moves through a list of elevation rasters (ERDAS IMG format), extracting cells below a threshold, and finally merging them together.  I am currently running the script in the command prompt, as everything else opens new windows, or crashes in an attempt to.  The script gives the illusion that it works fine, except it seems to move on to the final merge before waiting for the workers to completely finish.

I have looked at several examples and few seem to have more than a couple of processes in the worker function.  None of which are arcpy geoprocesses.  So I guess my questions are essentially 1) Should I be using something other than pool.apply_async, such as pool.map or pool.apply? 2) Am I properly returning the path of the final polygon to the resultList?

Any criticism is welcome and greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

```
# Import modules
import arcpy, os, math
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
import multiprocessing
import time

# Check out licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

# Define functions
def worker_bee(inputRaster, scratch, addNum):   
    (path, lName) = os.path.split(inputRaster)
    (sName, ext) = os.path.splitext(lName)
    nameParts = sName.split("_")
    nameNumber = nameParts[-1]

    # Create scratch subfolder if not exists
    subFolder = scratch + "\\" + nameNumber + "_output" 
    if not os.path.exists(subFolder):os.makedirs(subFolder)
    # Set workspace to subfolder
    arcpy.env.workspace = subFolder
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
    arcpy.env.extent = "MAXOF"

    # Local Variables
    Expression = "Shape_Area >= 100"
    poly1 = subFolder + "\\poly1.shp"
    poly2 = subFolder + "\\poly2.shp"
    poly3 = subFolder + "\\poly3.shp"
    poly4 = subFolder + "\\poly4.shp"
    poly5 = subFolder + "\\poly5.shp"
    poly6 = subFolder + "\\poly6.shp"
    poly7 = subFolder + "\\poly7.shp"
    outName = scratch + "\\ABL_" + nameNumber + ".shp"

    #### Perform calculations ###
    # Map Algebra (replace -9999 with 9999)
    inRasterCon = Con(inputRaster, 9999, inputRaster, "Value = -9999")
    # Filter DEM to smooth out low outliers
    filterOut = Filter(inRasterCon, "LOW", "DATA")
    # Determine raster MINIMUM value and calculate threshold
    filterMinResult = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(filterOut, "MINIMUM")
    filterMin = filterMinResult.getOutput(0)
    threshold = (float(filterMin) + float(addNum))
    # Map Algebra (values under threshold)
    outCon = Con(filterOut <= threshold, 1, "")
    arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(outCon, poly1, "SIMPLIFY", "Value")
    # Dissolve parts
    arcpy.Dissolve_management(poly1, poly2, "", "", "SINGLE_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")    
    # Select parts larger than 100 sq m
    arcpy.Select_analysis(poly2, poly3, Expression)
    # Process: Eliminate Polygon Part
    arcpy.EliminatePolygonPart_management(poly4, poly5, "PERCENT", "0 SquareMeters", "10", "CONTAINED_ONLY")
    # Select parts larget than 100 sq m
    arcpy.Select_analysis(poly5, poly6, Expression)
    # Simplify Polygon
    arcpy.SimplifyPolygon_cartography(poly6, poly7, "BEND_SIMPLIFY", "3 Meters", "3000 SquareMeters", "RESOLVE_ERRORS", "KEEP_COLLAPSED_POINTS")
    # Smooth Polygon
    outShape = arcpy.SmoothPolygon_cartography(poly7, outName, "PAEK", "3 Meters", "FIXED_ENDPOINT", "FLAG_ERRORS").getOutput(0)
    ### Calculations complete ###

    # Delete scratch subfolder
    arcpy.Delete_management(subFolder)

    print("Completed " + outShape + "...")
    return outShape

resultList = []
def log_result(result):
    resultList.append(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
    # Read in parameters
    inFolder = raw_input("Input Folder: ")#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    addElev = raw_input("Number of elevation units to add to minimum: ")

    # Create scratch folder workspace
    scratchFolder = inFolder + "\\scratch" 
    if not os.path.exists(scratchFolder):os.makedirs(scratchFolder)

    # Local variables
    dec_num = str(float(addElev) - int(float(addElev)))[1:]
    outNameNum = dec_num.replace(".", "")
    outMerge = inFolder + "\\ABL_" + outNameNum + ".shp"

    # Print core usage
    cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    print("Using " + str(cores) + " cores...")

    #Start timing
    start = time.clock()

    # List input tiles
    arcpy.env.workspace = inFolder
    inTiles = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "IMG")
    tileList = []
    for tile in inTiles:
        tileList.append(inFolder + "\\" + tile)

    # Create a Pool of subprocesses
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cores)

    print("Adding jobs to multiprocessing pool...")
    for tile in tileList:
        # Add the job to the multiprocessing pool asynchronously
        pool.apply_async(worker_bee, (tile, scratchFolder, addElev), callback = log_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # Merge the temporary outputs
    print("Merging temporary outputs into shapefile " + outMerge + "...")
    arcpy.Merge_management(resultList, outMerge)

    # Clean up temporary data
    print("Deleting temporary data ...")
    for result in results:
        try:
            arcpy.Delete_management(result)
        except:
            pass

    # Stop timing and report duration
    end = time.clock()
    duration = end - start
    hours, remainder = divmod(duration, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    print("Completed in " + hours + "hrs " + minutes + "min " + seconds + "sec")
```

Comment: to 2.: from my understanding `log_result` exists in every process and will be called locally only. If you use map then you will be fine.

Comment: What is so special about geoprocesses, what is a geoprocess?

Comment: A geoprocess is a GIS operation used to manipulate spatial data